# IEEE publication with author images and CV at the end

Tags: ieeetran

I need to add an image for each author including the CV at the end of an IEEE publication.
The word template looks like this :

- Image should be left aligned
- author name in bold
- CV in normal char
- 1 text block for each author of this paper.

Is there any Latex package doing this for me, or do I have to code myself?

Comment: See IEEEtran.cls from CTAN, or download a newer version from https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention the IEEE journal you are going to use. For this example it  was used `IEEE Transactions in Aerospace and Electronic Systems` whose articles typically include a biography and photo.

It was added a patch to change the font size to normal size (in the journals they are printed in footnotesize)

You must use the use the `IEEEbiography` environment to add the author`s photo.

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip]{<image file>}}]% add the photo
    {<author name>}
bio text ...
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

[image: a]

The same patch and environment will work with `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 
    
\documentclass{IEEEtaes}

\usepackage{color,array,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\IEEEbiography}
{\fontsize{8.25}{10}\selectfont}
{\normalsize}
{}{}
%************************************* 

\jvol{XX}
\jnum{XX}
\jmonth{XXXXX}
\paper{1234567}
\pubyear{2022}
\doiinfo{TAES.2022.Doi Number}  

\setcounter{page}{1}

\begin{document}

\title{IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems} 

\author{FIRST A. AUTHOR}
\member{Fellow, IEEE}
\affil{National Institute of Standards and Technology, Boulder, CO, USA} 

\author{SECOND B. AUTHOR}
\affil{Colorado State University, Fort Collins, CO 80523, USA} 

\author{THIRD C. AUTHOR Jr.}
\member{Member, IEEE}
\affil{University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 80309, USA}


\receiveddate{Manuscript received XXXXX 00, 0000; revised XXXXX 00, 0000; accepted XXXXX 00, 0000.\\
This paragraph of the first footnote will contain the date on which you submitted your paper for review, }

\corresp{The name of the corresponding author appears after the financial information, e.g. {\itshape (Corresponding author: M. Smith)}. Here you may also indicate if authors contributed equally or if there are co-first authors.}

\authoraddress{The next few paragraphs should contain the authors' current affiliations, including current address and e-mail.}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}This document provides a guide for preparing articles for IEEE Transactions, Journals, and Letters. Use this document as a template if you are using {\itshape LaTeX}. Otherwise, use this as an instruction set. The electronic file of your article will be formatted further at IEEE. Titles should be written in uppercase and lowercase letters, not all uppercase.  Abstracts must be a single paragraph. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}Enter keywords or phrases in alphabetical order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank e-mail to \href{mailto:keywords@ieee.org}{keywords@ieee.org} or visit \href{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}{\url{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}}
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
Reference numbers are set flush left and form a column of their own, hanging out beyond the body of the reference. The reference numbers are on the line, enclosed in square brackets. In all references, the given name of the author or editor is abbreviated to the initial only and precedes the last name. Use them all; use \emph{et al}. only if names are not given or if there are more than 6 authors. Use commas around Jr., Sr., and III in names. Abbreviate conference titles. When citing IEEE Transactions, provide the issue number, page range, volume number, month if available, and year. When referencing a patent, provide the day and the month of issue, or application. References may not include all information; please obtain and include relevant information. Do not combine references. There must be only one reference with each number. If there is a URL included with the reference, it can be included at the end of the reference.

\section{CONCLUSION}
A conclusion section is not required. Although a conclusion may review the main points of the article, do not replicate the abstract as the conclusion. A conclusion might elaborate on the importance of the work or suggest applications and extensions.

When submitting your final files on a hybrid OA journal you will have the opportunity to designate your article as ``open access'' if you agree to pay the IEEE open access fee. Please select the appropriate choice. Immediately after you have submitted your final files through ScholarOne Manuscripts you will be automatically redirected to the IEEE electronic copyright form wizard. Please complete the copyright at that time to avoid publication delays

%%************************************************<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip]{example-image-a}}]{First A. Author} (Fellow, IEEE) and all authors may include biographies if the publication allows. Biographies are often not included in conference-related papers. Please check the Information for Authors to confirm. Author photos should be current, professional images of the head and shoulders. The first paragraph may contain a place and/or date of birth (list place, then date). Next, the author's educational background is listed. 
\end{IEEEbiography}%

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip]{example-image-b}}]{Second B. Author}(Fellow, IEEE) and all authors may include biographies if the publication allows. Biographies are often not included in conference-related papers. Please check the Information for Authors to confirm. Author photos should be current, professional images of the head and shoulders. The first paragraph may contain a place and/or date of birth (list place, then date). Next, the author's educational background is listed.    
\end{IEEEbiography}%

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip]{example-image-c}}]{Third C. Author Jr.} (Fellow, IEEE) and all authors may include biographies if the publication allows. Biographies are often not included in conference-related papers. Please check the Information for Authors to confirm. 
\end{IEEEbiography}%
\hfill

\end{document}
```